# pg_regress: initdb failed , while trying to run make installcheck command for Apache AGE

Tags: apache-age

I have installed PostgreSQL ( PG11 ) and using the AGE source code of master branch ( supports PG11 ), also I do the `make install` command successfully , LOAD AGE and use it smoothly without problems.
But now I am trying to run `the make installcheck` command but actually it gives "pg_regress: initdb failed" error.

Notes :

- mainly using windows OS , use ubuntu on top of it (WSL tool)
- installed PG 11.20 ( Major 11 , Minor 20 )
- cloned age repo , working with master branch checked out .

I already checked that the age , PostgreSQL installed in Linux directory files not **/mnt/**  but also same problem , I want to use it to check the regression tests ( to use it later on in validating/debugging versions )

and here are some images of problem :

[image: PG version]

[image: pg_regress: initdb failed]

Thanks for your help and collaboration :) !

Answer (score 0):

when you use `make installcheck` dont use `sudo`. If that doesn't fix that make sure you have permissions on the `/bin` in the path `/usr/local/<name_of_folder_you_installed_postgres>/bin` by using
`sudo chown <username> /usr/local/<name_of_folder_you_installed_postgres>/bin`

Answer (score 0):

Go to the log file specified in the error & look for the information there.
Most probably it would look something like this:

```
Running in no-clean mode.  Mistakes will not be cleaned up.
initdb: error: cannot be run as root
initdb: hint: Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will own the server process.
```

Now what you need to do is execute the command without "sudo" or switch to unprivileged user. This can be done by:

```
su <username>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `installcheck` command, it is recommended not to include `sudo`. Additionally, make sure to include the `PG_CONFIG` flag in your command as follows:

```
make PG_CONFIG=/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_config installcheck
```

In some cases, permission issues may arise, requiring you to grant permissions to your PostgreSQL directory. To do this, you can use the following command:

```
sudo chown -R /usr/lib/postgresql
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use sudo with make check. and first give all permission to main user by chown then try make install check command

Answer (score 0):

Grant user level permission / change the owner of the directory (in which PostgreSQL is installed) to the current user and re run without using `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

When you are to use `installcheck`, you should not use `sudo` with it.Now you should run the command without elevated privileges `sudo` or switch to a regular user unprivileged account.
I hope this would help.